# String join issue

Tags: .net

```
/*

Instructions
------------
Write a LINQ query that results in all fruits that are a single word (i.e. exclude fruits like "Goji berries", as well as empty entries).
Sort the results by the length of the word, with the longest word first and the shortest word last.
The results should be lowercased.

*/

using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static readonly string[] Fruits = new []
    {
        "Acai",
        "Apple",
        "Apricots",
        "Banana",
        "Blackberry",
        "",
        "Blueberry",
        "Cherries",
        "Coconut",
        "Cranberry ",
        "Cucumber",
        "Currents",
        "Dates",
        "Durian",
        "Fig",
        "Goji berries",
        "Gooseberry",
        "Grapefruit",
        "Grapes",
        "Jackfruit",
        "Kiwi",
        "Kumquat",
        "Lemon",
        "Lime",
        "Lucuma",
        " Lychee",
        "Mango",
        "Mangosteen",
        "Melon",
        "",
        "Mulberry",
        "Nectarine",
        "Orange",
        "Papaya",
        "Passion Fruit",
        "Peach",
        "Pear",
        "Pineapple ",
        "Plum",
        "Pomegranate",
        "Pomelo",
        "Prickly Pear",
        "Prunes",
        "Strawberries",
        "Tangerine",
        "Watermelon"
    };)

    public void Main()
    {
        // Do your work here...
 []

        Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", String.Join("*", new);
    }
}
```

What is going on? I am not sure I get it. What is the solution here?

I'm trying various approaches, but the method does not seem to support what is being done here at all.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

I'm a bit lost in this one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `"String.Join("*", new)"` - What are you even trying to do with the keyword `new` here?  Aren't you trying to join the array `Fruits`?  Also, "WTF" isn't really a meaningful description of the problem.  We can't see your screen.  Show any errors you're receiving, explain what you're trying and why, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `)` in the line, and you shouldn't use the keyword `new` as variable name.

```
Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", String.Join("*", result));
```

In the part that is your assignment you would create the variable and assign the result to it.

This doesn't solve the assignment, instead it gets the first three fruits, but it shows how to create the variable and work with the data:

```
string[] result = Fruits.Take(3).ToArray();
```